# How does this delete an element from an array?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am using this book data structures and algorithms in java to learn about (you guessed it) - data structures and algorithms. This piece of code confuses me. I have tested it and it works but i don't see where in the code we specify to delete 55 exactly?

I see that we search for it in the array and move data elements up the index but don't see where we tell the compiler to delete 55.

```
    searchKey = 55; // delete item with key 55
    for(j=0; j<nElems; j++) // look for it
      if(arr[j] == searchKey)
        break;
    for(int k=j; k<nElems-1; k++) // move higher ones down
      arr[k] = arr[k+1];
    nElems--; // decrement size
```

Comment: this code will not compile....j is not visible in your next loop....what are you trying to say?

Comment: Are there any missing braces from the original code from your book?

Comment: j is obviously defined somewhere further up the code. No, no missing braces, just horrible format ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise, this code does not delete an array element; it overrides it.

Note how `j` is declared outside the first loop, and used in the second loop to initialize the value of `k`. The first loop walks `j` through the array, until `j` "points" to the element with the value of `55`. When this happens, the code exits the loop through `break`, so when the second loop reads `j`, it still points to the location in the array where `55` is stored. Now the second loop copies elements from `k+1`-st location into `k`-th, "overriding" the value of `55` on the first iteration, and then moving the rest of the values in the consecutive iterations.

Consider this example:

```
Index:  0  1  2  3  4  5
Value: 30 40 55 60 70 80
```

After the first loop `j` is set to `2`. Each iteration of the second loop changes the array as follows:

```
Index:        0  1  2  3  4  5
Iteration 0: 30 40 55 60 70 80
Iteration 1: 30 40 60 60 70 80
Iteration 2: 30 40 60 70 70 80
Iteration 3: 30 40 60 70 80 80
```

At this point `nElems` is decremented, making sure that the last element (i.e. `80`) is disregarded if the program runs again.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of example, suppose:

```
searchKey = 3
arr = {1,2,3,4,0,0,0}
nElems = 4
```

This means we have an array with seven slots, but the last three elements of the array are unused by the surrounding data structure.

The first `for` loop is simply looking for the index, `j`, that contains `searchKey` (`searchValue` would have been a better name, but alas).  Once it finds the correct index, it `break`s, leaving `j` set.  In our example, `j = 2` at the end of the first loop.  Nothing has been changed yet, we've just found the index we want to clear.

The second `for` loop does the actual leg work by shifting everything after our found element down one index (and overwriting the found index in the process), so `arr[2]` is set to `arr[3]` and `arr[3]` is set to `arr[4]` and so on.  At the end of the second loop we have

```
arr = {1,2,4,4,0,0,0}
```

Finally, we decrement `nElems` by one, so that there are now only three elements in the data structure.  The last four elements in the array (`4,0,0,0`) are all now garbage that will get written over if more elements are added.

Answer (score 0):

It is overwritten by the first iteration of the second for loop.